# Trouble with a function in R, "BinHist"

Tags: r

I'm trying to use a bit of code that I found in an academic journal (). I'm new-ish to R. I keep getting an error when I reach the code calling up the function "binHist" that says "could not find the function "binhist". I can't figure out if it's in a library/ package I need to install or if there's another problem with the code. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's the code I extracted from the article:

```
whichData = yourData 
baseH = data.frame()
RunningSum = 0
for (i in 2:16) {
tempBin = NULL
tempBin = binhist(i, whichData$rt)
theMean = sum(tempBin)/(i)
Divisor = sum(tempBin)
new = data.frame()
for (j in 1:ncol(tempBin)) {
grabVal = (tempBin[j] - theMean)^2
names(grabVal) <- NULL
new = c(new,grabVal)
}
extra = i - ncol(tempBin)
NewSum = Reduce("+",new) + extra*((0 - theMean)^2)
StdDev = sqrt(NewSum /(i-1))
RowVal = StdDev /Divisor
RunningSum = RunningSum + RowVal
baseH = c(baseH, list(tempBin))
}
paste("Number of Trials:",Divisor)
paste("Modulo-Binning Score (MBS): ",RunningSum)
library(plyr)
baseNow = do.call(rbind.fill,baseH)
```

Comment: That error means you either mistyped the function name, or it's in a package that you haven't attached. It looks like there's a `binhist` function in the `bda` package. I'm sure that the methods section of that paper will tell you what packages were used. Be careful, though: R is case sensitive. So `binhist` is **not** the same thing as `binHist`. You use the two interchangeable in your question

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried installing and loading up the bda package with binhist. I still get the message "Error in binhist(i, whichData$rt) : could not find function "binhist". Any other ideas? (fyi: thanks for the note about capitalization. I wasn't sure; the code from the article has the "H" capitalized, but I've tried it both ways to make sure).

Comment: Did you attach the package with `library(bda)`? You can check out functions by calling help on them with `?binhist`. One question mark will search for the functions in attached packages. If you can't find it, try 2 question marks `??binhist` to search all packages

Comment: You can also search https://www.rdocumentation.org for functions by name. It will tell you what packages have a function with that name and show you the documentation

Comment: I did attach the bda package, but it didn't work. After doing the ??binhist search, I found a package called occugene that has it listed. After installing and attaching it, I get the same result. Thanks again for your reply and for all of the tips--I would have never known how to search for functions & documentation with the ? and ??

Comment: `occugene` has `binHist`, so if you're trying to run the code you posted, you'll need to capitalize the `h` in `binHist`

Comment: Yeah. I tried both ways. No dice.

Comment: When is the paper from? And were you able to find anything in the methods section? `binhist` only exists in very old versions of the `bda` package, while `binHist` is in `occugene` which must be installed through [Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/occugene.html)